# How to register a WmfImageHandler with Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, wmf

I wish to open and save .wmf/emf files but I cannot figure out how to register the ImageHandler.
Can someone pleace help.

I have tried to look at the Docs for pillow but I cannot understand how to do it.

Edit:
Output from python -m PIL:
[image: patrt 1]

[image: part 2]

[image: part 3]

[image: part 4]

[image: part 5]

[image: part 6]

Comment: What are `wmfúemf` files?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry thats a typo. I corrected it

Comment: What OS are you using? And can you click [edit] and paste in the output from `python -m PIL` please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I adderd the output and Im using Windows 10.